# Why does changing router's DNS servers fix issues with accessing network resources on VPN?

Tags: networking, router, vpn, dns, firewall

I had issues being able to access the network resources (intranet, shared drives, folders, etc) when using my work VPN from home, until I changed the DNS servers of my router from the ISP default to Google (8.8.8.8). Once doing that, and resetting the router, everything became accessible. I went back and forth a few times to confirm that is exactly was fixed it. So why does the DNS servers of my router affect whether or not I can access network resources on my work from home VPN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your VPN client is probably set to try the DNS existing server, and is set
to only uses the
one provided by the VPN if the existing DNS server returns a negative answer.

This means that the DNS server of your ISP returns an answer for your VPN
resources, even though it knows nothing about them.
The Google server however does the right thing and gives a negative answer for
such resources.

You should complain to both your ISP and the VPN provider,
the first for giving wrong DNS answers, and the second for not setting
its DNS server as first in the DNS order
(unless if the VPN server provider is yourself...).

Answer (score 1):

> ... until I changed the DNS servers of my router from the ISP default
>   to Google (8.8.8.8). Once doing that, and resetting the router,
>   everything became

Does ISP provide DNSes over DHCP or did you have to type them?
DNS-es sometimes got changed so it's worth to check them.

You can try to use the dig tool (Linux) or nslookup (Windows) to test them.

This might sound stupid but if I understand your post, you use external router box.
After you alter your router's DNSes.
Do you save the config in router-s ROM or just click OK and leave?

If it's a low-cost router reset might not always do a reset
or as a design, it might not reset everything (like your DNS IPs)... :/

Long story short - VPN is just yet another "tunnel" to route the data to/from. It is not DNS aware... Your computer needs to know (using DNS) where should it send data (localhost, eht0: your VPN f.ex. or maybe eth1 - like 2nd LAN card).

The question is do your ISP DNSes know anything about your VPN?

Comment: Default DNSes are via DHCP. Router settings showed 0.0.0.0 when using default (DHCP). I changed it from 0.0.0.0 to 8.8.8.8 and then the VPN resources became available. Nothing was saved to the router ROM, just a normal save to the configuration. I'm not sure what the ISP can tell about the VPN.

Comment: This answer is absolutely not true : VPN induces a network, and such a network has its DHCP & DNS servers. It's much more than just a tunnel, or computers would keep their IP address while on VPN. I don't understand upvotes to this answer.

Comment: -PJS1987 - If your router says 0.0.0.0 then the DHCP client software in the router is broken or incompatible with DHCP server on the other side, or DHCP server does not provide DNS IPs at all - and that is imo nearly 99 percent true. Try querying your ISP and type DNSes by hand.

Comment: @harrymc - Yes, VPN is a network but who said this network needs DHCP or DNS at all? There might be one but if not needed, there can be none... Am I wrong?

Comment: Mostly wrong : The VPN virtual network adapter, when active, gets another IP address than the one the computer has when it's inactive. This of course implies a DHCP server of some kind. To communicate then with other computers through that "tunnel" a DNS server is required. The function of the VPN client here is to add the DNS server it receives from the VPN server to the current one, either in addition or in replacement. It's rare for a VPN server not to return a DNS server, although possible.

Comment: Neah. you must be thinking on some kind of 'tap' connections, where internal DHCP and routing are needed. 'tun' does not need this (only routing)... I've been using such since quite a few years... This had to be a long stroy short...